# Picasa Public Web Album Thumbnail Retrieval

Tags: picasa

Given a URL to a public Picasa Web album (album is not mine), is there a way to retrieve the thumbnail  for that album? The Picasa web API seems centered around knowing the Picasa username but I don't know the username, just the public link to the album.

Should be a simple question. For YouTube it is simply a tweak on the video URL but it doesn't seem to be so for Picasa Web. Am I missing something here?